# Need help on Run-time error 3129 with SELECT statement

Tags: vba

Code is below. Getting errors on first and last lines. I think there is an extra `(` or else missing `)` on 2nd line but that wouldn't explain the error on the last line.

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlStr)

strSQL = "SELECT fct_monitoring.MeasureID FROM fct_monitoring WHERE MeasureID IN (" & _
    Chr(34) & "CAUTI_Rate_All" & Chr(34) & "," & _
    Chr(34) & "CDI_LabID" & Chr(34) & "," & _
    Chr(34) & "CLABSI_Rate_All" & Chr(34) & "," & _
    Chr(34) & "Falls_Injury" & Chr(34) & "," & _
    Chr(34) & "READ-1" & Chr(34) & ")" & _
    Chr(34) & "CAUTI_SIR_All" & Chr(34) & "," & _
    Chr(34) & "CDI_SIR" & Chr(34) & "," & _
    Chr(34) & "CLABSI_SIR_All" & Chr(34) & "," & _
    " GROUP BY fct_monitoring.MeasureID;"

Set msrRst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
```

Comment: No, that would specifically explain the error on the last line.

Comment: "Getting errors" is not a very useful description of the exact problems you're having with your code.

Comment: Missing the closing parenthesis for your IN list.

Comment: @TimWilliams It's on the 6th line.

Comment: @GSerg Missing from the correct place then?  Also quotes around values should be single quotes not double.

Comment: I'm out of practice with MSAccess sql - I think double quotes will work not sure though. Edit - yes they do work. This is one reason why MSAccess is superior to other databases.

Comment: OP - maybe edit your question to add the SQL string you're trying to create?

Comment: Thanks all. Definitely corrected the ) on the 6th line to be a comma instead. When I debug, the error points to the first line, DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlStr), if that is more helpful. It's run-time error 3129, Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: No sorry that doesn't help - it just means there is a problem with the sql (which we already know).

Answer (score 0):

You really want to just print out the sql statement - it is too error prone to try to work out all these concatenations.

```
strSQL = "SELECT fct_monitoring.MeasureID FROM fct_monitoring WHERE MeasureID IN (" & _ 
    Chr(34) & "CAUTI_Rate_All" & Chr(34) & "," & _ 
    Chr(34) & "CDI_LabID" & Chr(34) & "," & _ 
    Chr(34) & "CLABSI_Rate_All" & Chr(34) & "," & _ 
    Chr(34) & "Falls_Injury" & Chr(34) & "," & _ 
    Chr(34) & "READ-1" & Chr(34) & ")" & _ 
    Chr(34) & "CAUTI_SIR_All" & Chr(34) & "," & _ 
    Chr(34) & "CDI_SIR" & Chr(34) & "," & _ 
    Chr(34) & "CLABSI_SIR_All" & Chr(34) & "," & _ 
    " GROUP BY fct_monitoring.MeasureID;"

Debug.Print(sqlStr)
```

With that debug output you can look at something that makes a bit more sense (it should be a sql statement you can read better - if you want, you can even paste it into a query in sql design view and run it.

Although actually in this better format, I think I can see that probably after READ-1 you have a parenthesis that should be a quote, and after CLABSI_SIR_All you have a comma where you should have a parenthesis (this looks like someone decided to move a line around).

Comment: Topsail, thanks for your reply. I didn't write this code and am not versed in VBA for Access. When I pasted the statement into a query and ran, I received another error- Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. Are you pasting the debug output into a query? Or the vba code? It should be the former - Debug.print(sqlStr) will print output to the immediate window. That should be the actual sql string.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible to be sure from your posted code exactly what you want to do, but this should maybe be close:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT distinct fct_monitoring.MeasureID " & _
         "   FROM fct_monitoring WHERE MeasureID IN " & _
         "('CAUTI_Rate_All','CDI_LabID','CLABSI_Rate_All','Falls_Injury', " & _
         " 'READ-1','CAUTI_SIR_All','CDI_SIR','CLABSI_SIR_All')"
```

No need for all that `Chr(34)` since you can use single-quotes.